# How to dynamically link libraries in automake?

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, automake, building, launchpad

I'm trying to build a package on lauchpad. For it to build I need to set a static path using the LDADD variable in automake:

```
relay_LDADD = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 $(RELAY_LIBS)
```

This compiles on the 64 bit build but fails on the 32 bit build. I tried using PKG_CHECK_MODULES but it says

```
No package 'm' found
No package 'X11' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
```

I know it not a non standard path since launchpad is doing the building? How can I get this to work?

The build failed without the libraries specified even though the package specifies them in the build-requires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have tried to outwit the buid-system, and it has outwitted you.

It's generally a bad idea to hard-code paths.

Debian (and ubuntu is just a derivative), has started to ship binaries (like libraries) in architecture-dependent directories, to allow installations for multiple architectures on a single system.

These libraries are installed into `/usr/lib/<host-triplet>`, where `<host-triplet>` depends on the architecture; e.g. `x86_64-linux-gnu` is the *amd64* architecture for systems with a *linux* and the *gnu* tools.
a 32bit system would typically have a host-triplet of `i386-linux-gnu`.

Since you are hard-coding the library path to a 64bit location( `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so`) this fails on all systems but *64bit/linux/gnu*.

Instead you should just tell the linker to link against the *m* library (`libm`), resp the *X11* library (`libX11`).
Let the linker care for the correct architecture to pick:

```
relay_LDADD = -lm -lX11 $(RELAY_LIBS)
```

In general, if you want to link against a library *foo*, that provides a library-file `libfoo.so` you would use `-lfoo` (stripping away  the leading `lib` and the trailing `.so`).

However, sometimes this is not enough; in those cases your library might use `pkg-config` to provide the full `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` needed to compile/link against this library.

e.g. if I want to use `libquicktime`:

```
 $ pkg-config --cflags libquicktime
 -I/usr/include/lqt
 $ pkg-config --libs libquicktime
 -lquicktime -lpthread -lm -lz -ldl
```

So I would use something like:

```
  myprog_CFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --cflags libquicktime)
  myprog_LDADD += $(shell pkg-config --libs libquicktime)
```

That would work in any GNU(?) Makefile (not related to autotools).
In an autotools project, you would probably move the pkg-config check into `configure`, using the m4-macro `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`

Comment: Thats great! Whats the command for finding the linker flag for a library?